# Ion Auth - "sess_destroy()" Fatal Error when logging out

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I have downloaded the very latest version of IonAuth for Codeigniter on GitHub. It is a very good library however when I try to logout after logging in I get the following error (which I've had in previous builds) - I know I can just comment the lines out but is there a reason for the errors?

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Session::sess_destroy() ....\Ion_auth.php on line 381
```

Comment: Is codeigniter's session library being loaded? ($this->load->library('session');)

Perhaps try autoloading it in config/autoload.php

Comment: You don't need to load `session library` if you are loading `$this->load->library('ion_auth')` in constructor because `ion_auth` will automatically load the `session library`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just kept them commented out.. seems to wrk